# count values over time interval

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Please could someone assist with a SQL View.

I have a table called LoginActivity

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginActivity](
[LoAc_ActivityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LoAc_UserID] [int] NULL,
[LoAc_Login] [datetime] NULL,
[LoAc_logout] [datetime] NULL,
[LoAc_Duration] [numeric](24, 6) NULL,
)
```

Which records login/logout times with the user id and returns data such as below.

```
779     1   2017-11-03 08:07:41.000  2017-11-03 08:09:14.000    1.000000
780     1   2017-11-04 08:09:19.000  2017-11-04 08:27:19.000    17.000000
781     2   2017-11-04 08:27:22.000  2017-11-04 08:35:11.000    7.000000
782     3   2017-11-04 08:35:18.000  2017-11-04 08:58:12.000    19.000000
783     4   2017-11-04 08:35:22.000  2017-11-04 08:58:12.000    19.000000
```

I need to create a view that counts the number of users where LoAc_Login was within the past 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours and finally 4 hours. I would like to present the data like below.

```
 WithinHour  1HourAgo 2HoursAgo 3HoursAgo 4HoursAgo
 2           3        5         0         2
```

Thanks.

Comment: That seems great. What's stopping you?

Comment: please share expected result as per your sample data and also any query you might have tried

Comment: Apologies.
The listing with ID's Times and Duration are presented in the select table statement.
The summary counts is what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like;

```
SELECT 
    sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(H,getdate(),LoAc_Login) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(H,getdate(),LoAc_Login) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WithinHour,
    sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(H,getdate(),LoAc_Login) >= 1 AND DATEDIFF(H,getdate(),LoAc_Login) < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OneHourAgo,
    etc. 
FROM LoginActivity
```

*Not Tested, syntax may be off as typing quickly, but hopefully you get the idea?*

Comment: just a slight syntax amendment needed at the end of the case statement, thank you Milney